# Сортировка коллекции. Интерфейс Comparator

Tags: java, сортировка, arraylist

Возникла необходимость избавиться от второго метода сравнения `compare`однако после его удаления программа не компилируется. Подскажите в чем может быть загвоздка?

```
public class Car implements Comparator<ArrayList> {
    private int speed;

    public int getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public Car(int speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Car>> listsOfCars = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
            int a = rand.nextInt(50);
            ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
            for (int j = 0; j < a; j++) {
                cars.add(new Car(a));
            }
            listsOfCars.add(cars);
        }
        Collections.sort(listsOfCars, SizeComparator);
        for (ArrayList<Car> cars : listsOfCars) {
            System.out.println(cars.size());
        }
    }

    public static Comparator<ArrayList> SizeComparator = new Comparator<ArrayList>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ArrayList arrlist1, ArrayList arrlist2) {
            return arrlist1.size() - arrlist2.size();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int compare(ArrayList arrlist1, ArrayList arrlist2) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: удали implements Comparator<ArrayList> в объявлении класса

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov спасибо, все работает! Если не затруднит, расскажите почему надо было удалять?

Comment: Потому что вы определили что класс может сравнивать, но при этом делать этого он не умеет, т.к. метода  для сравнения нет.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov Еще раз спасибо Вам!

Comment: @Oleg пожалуйста

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В объявлении класса у вас указано, что он реализует интерфейс `Comparator`, но при этом, сам класс не реализует данный метод.

Чтобы код компилировался, нужно либо

- Реализовать данный метод
- Объявить класс абстрактным и оставить реализацию на откуп классам наследникам.